# Renombrar una columna dentro de una función

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

tengo un conjunto de datos que convierto a otras unidades y entonces el nombre de la columna debe ser cambiado para que coincidan ademas que es bueno estandarizar nombres de variables cuando tienden usarse en múltiples ocasiones, pero renombrarlas esto es muy tedioso

Aqui un fragmento del conjunto de datos:

```
Msuelo <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, ID_UACh = 383:387, pH = c(6.21, 6.27, 
6.24, 6.18, 6.31), C..E...dS.m.1. = c(0.55, 0.18, 0.18, 0.17, 
0.17), M..O..... = c(2.29, 2.89, 3.09, 2.62, 3.23), N..Total.... = c(0.07, 
0.05, 0.02, 0.08, 0.07), P..mg.kg.1. = c("26.42", "33.61", "37.21", 
"23.12", "46.2"), K..mg.kg.1. = c(474L, 566L, 574L, 588L, 490L
), Ca..mg.kg.1. = c(2023L, 2027L, 2522L, 2066L, 2835L), Mg..mg.kg.1. = c(460L, 
475L, 471L, 477L, 472L), Dens..Apar....g.cm.3. = c(1.19, 1.19, 
1.12, 1.22, 1.12), Arena.... = c(25.5, 27.5, 27.5, 33.5, 27.5
), Limo.... = c(45.3, 43.3, 47.3, 41.3, 47.3), Arcilla.... = c(29.2, 
29.2, 25.2, 25.2, 25.2), Textura = c("FRANCO-ARCILLOSO", "FRANCO-ARCILLOSO", 
"FRANCO", "FRANCO", "FRANCO")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

he creado una función para hacer la conversion de mis datos

```
  ppm2meq <-function(x, element='element'){
  if(element=='Ca'){meq <- x*(2/40.078)*0.1 }
  if(element=='Mg'){meq <- x*(2/24.305 )*0.1}
  if(element=='K'){meq <- x*(1/39.0983)*0.1}
  return(meq)
}
```

y la uso de la siguiente forma

```
Msuelo$Ca..mg.kg.1. <- ppm2meq(Msuelo$Ca..mg.kg.1.,element='Ca')
```

y hasta aquí todos bien

pero no he conseguido renombrar la columna asi sin éxito:

```
if(element=='Ca'){meq <- x*(2/40.078)*0.1 ; rename(x,'Ca_meq100g' = name) }

 #Error in UseMethod("rename") : 
 #no applicable method for 'rename' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
 #Called from: rename(., x = "Ca_meq/100g")
```

entre otras formas que tampoco dieron resultado, alguna idea si esto es posible como lo planteo o debería reconsiderad plantearlo de otra forma?

los leo, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se entiende bien donde estas renombrando la columna.

Si el cambio de nombre lo estas haciendo dentro de la función `ppm2meq`, esto no  sería posible, porque esa función recibe un número `x` y entrega otro número `meq`, el cual no es un dataframe por lo que no tiene columnas.

Si lo que quieres hacer es cambiar el nombre de la columna `Ca..mg.kg.1.` del dataframe `Msuelo` por `Ca_meq100g`, lo puedes hacer asignando el nuevo nombre así:

```
colnames(Msuelo)[9] <- "Ca_meq100g"
```

El 9 debes cambiarlo dependiendo del lugar en que se encuentre la columna dentro del dataframe.

Si utilizas los paquetes del tidyverse tiene la opción de hacerlo con `rename`

```
library(dplyr)

Msuelo <- rename(Msuelo, Ca_meq100g = Ca..mg.kg.1.)
```